# best practice for sql scripts syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have sql file that contains long Inserst.
the problem is that when I want for example to edit column number12 I have to start counting the columns in the values area and its very confusing.

they looks something like :

[image]

witch is very confusing for updating since you have to find which value belongs to which column.

is there another way to write Insert script so it will be more easy to mach column with its values ? or maybe there's a tool that can help ?

maybe something like -

```
Insert tableName column1 = '10', column2 = '5' , column3 = 'asdsd' ....
```

**P.S - to see the image right click on it and 'Open in new tab'**

Comment: What database are you using (and what version)?

Comment: SQL server 2008 but basically those scripts are attached to my project
that is a class library in c# visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1):

Use two lines:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE  (COLUMN1, COLUMN2       , COLUMN3)
            VALUES (Value1 , "Long Value 2", "..."  );
```

Comment: thanks but when you have more than 30 columns the alignment of the column against its field is not good.

Comment: Use tabs to keep them lined up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new way of inserting records that was introduced in SQL Server 2008.

```
insert into @MyTable 
  (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5,                   Column6) values
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6),
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6),
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6),
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6),
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6)
```

You need to keep the column names aligned with the data and when you have more lines than fit on a page you can either restart the insert or add a column comment line at an appropriate place

```
insert into @MyTable 
  (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5,                   Column6) values
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6),
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6),
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6),
--(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5,                   Column6) values
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6),
  (1,       2,       3,       4,       cast(6 as numeric(38,8))), 6)
```

You could also keep your data in an actual table and update the table instead. Use some tool to script the inserts from that table. For example generate scripts in Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple `INSERT` statements - one will do.

You can use a `SELECT` statement with `UNION` to insert multiple rows:

```
INSERT myTable (Col1, Col2)
SELECT val1, val2 UNION 
SELECT val3, val4
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008, the `VALUES` statement has an extension:

```
INSERT myTable (Col1, Col2)
VALUES (val1, val2),
(val3, val4)
```

See [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) for SQL Server on MSDN.

---

If you are talking about readability, you *could* use something like the following (though you will end up with a very long file), and coding this up will take lots of time:

```
INSERT myTable (Col1, Col2)
SELECT val1, -- Col1
       val2 -- Col2
UNION 
SELECT val3, -- Col1
       val4 -- Col2
```

There are no standard convention for what you want, as such scripts are meant for running in SQL, not for reading.

Comment: thanks but it does not solve my problem of confusing when have to change a value.

in example of two fields its piece of cake but my scripts has more than 30 fields.

Comment: @Erez - I have given another option regarding visibility, though I question the need to begin with.